# Cassandra New node not able to see in status

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, spark-cassandra-connector, cassandra-3.0

Hi I have added a new node in cassandra. I have done same changes in cassandra.yaml file in new node and below is the cassandra-rackdc.properties detail on both node. 
dc=DC1 rack=RAC1
From any node I can't see different node.

**Old existing node**

```
[root@cas1 apache-cassandra-2.1.3]# bin/nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.1.101  110.28 KB  256     ?       2616878e-d276-46d3-ad1c-01a2e8fd15c2  rack1
```

**New Node**

```
[root@cas2 apache-cassandra-2.1.3]# bin/nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.1.102  128.62 KB  256     ?       2616878e-d276-46d3-ad1c-01a2e8fd15c2  rack1
```

Both are vmware machine.

Comment: Did you change the - seeds configuration?

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to have same settings for the 2 nodes. You have to help the new node to discover the cluster it intends to join.

You do this by updating the seeds property in cassandra.yaml of the new node.

- seeds (Default: 127.0.0.1)
  A comma-delimited list of IP addresses used by gossip for bootstrapping new nodes joining a cluster. If your cluster includes multiple nodes, you must change the list from the default value to the IP address of one of the nodes.

Reference used: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html

Comment: Old server IP(192.168.1.101) I am using as seed in both server(New and Old).

Comment: Below detail I am usingin both server                                    cluster_name: 'Test Cluster', num_tokens: 256, authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator, authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer,                       
- seeds: "192.168.1.101,192.168.1.102", listen_address: 192.168.1.102, # broadcast_address: 1.2.3.4, rpc_address: 0.0.0.0,                                                                          
rpc_port: 9160, broadcast_rpc_address: 1.2.3.4, endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

Comment: Can you ping from new node to old node? Are you sure no firewall is coming in between? Check logs on new node. You must get something about what's going wrong.